# Replace Array Callback

Tags: php, arrays, callback, replace

I have a string like:

> ```
> "Hello ? my name is ? and i am ? years old."
> ```

Every "`?`" is a variable and I want to replace each variable by an array. So I have this array:

```
$data = array('Mister,','Tom','30');
```

So I am looking for a clean way to transform all `?` by its equally array index, so that I get:

> "Hello Mister, my name is Tom and i am 30 years old."

Also I want to pass a function like `ucfirst()` to each array entry when they are replaced.

Anybody has an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using preg_replace_callback:

```
$str = "Hello ? my name is ? and i am ? years old.";
$data = array('Mister,','Tom','30');
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\?/', function($match) use(&$data) {
    return ucfirst(array_shift($data));
}, $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) can do that (in combination with [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$array = array('Mister,', 'Tom', '30');
$new_string = str_replace(array('?', '?', '?'),
    array_map(function($v) { return ucfirst($v); }, $array),
    $old_string
);
```

Comment: that won't work as it replaces all occurences of ? with Mister

Comment: it replaces all occurrences of ? with Array

Comment: @NikoSams: My bad, that only works the other direction (search being an array, replace a string).

Answer (score 0):

[sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) with [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)?

[array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)?

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = 'String ? etc etc';
$string = preg_replace("/?/",array_shift($data), $string, 1);
$string = preg_replace("/?/",array_shift($data), $string, 1);
$string = preg_replace("/?/",array_shift($data), $string, 1);

echo $string
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the simplest code. It could easily be put in a loop. The 1 at the end is a limiter which says only once a time.

Comment: It's not my downvote. But i think the person thought it repeated too much.

Comment: Oh, I suppose i should put it into a loop then. Thanks! It was my upvote though ;)